# Why scrollView doesn't scroll?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have vertical scrollView with contentSize height larger than window height. But it doesn't scroll. It even doest scroll if I set `scrollView.contentSize.height = 2000`

Height of scrollView is calculated on viewWillAppear when I add childviewcontroller.

code is following

```
self.parentView.addSubview(gameInfoMainViewController!.view)
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.frame = self.parentView.bounds
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.frame.size.height = gameInfoMainViewControllerHeight!
```

on line where subview is added a delegate method is being called which is

```
func passGameInfoTeamsViewControllerHeight(height:CGFloat) {
    gameInfoTeamsViewControllerHeight = height
    parentView.frame.size.height = gameInfoTeamsViewControllerHeight!
    parentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize.height = gameInfoTeamsViewControllerHeight! + segmentedControll!.frame.height + headerView.frame.size.height + 64
}
```

The most strange thing is that scroll is working if I call this code again

```
self.parentView.addSubview(gameInfoMainViewController!.view)
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.frame = self.parentView.bounds
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
gameInfoMainViewController!.view.frame.size.height = gameInfoMainViewControllerHeight!
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you use constraints/autolayout?

Comment: Is user interaction turned on?